# Relation between electrical conductance of a dielectric layer between two spheres and distance to the spheres

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electricity

> The space between two concentric spheres is filled with dielectric, the electrical conductance of which depends only on the distance to the spheres. Find the law of change of electrical conductance $\lambda (r)$ if the power density of heat loss during current flow is the same in all points of the dielectric layer.

So here are my thoughts: according to Joule–Lenz law the power density of heat loss $v = \lambda E^2$ where $\lambda$ is electrical conductance and $E$ is electric field. We have $\lambda=\lambda(r)$, then we have $v\equiv const$ (as it has the same value in all points of the layer), and after that I assumed that $E=E(r)$. So $\lambda(r)=\frac{v}{E^2(r)}$.

The next thing: the system we are looking at can be actually viewed as a spherical capacitor (there are two concentric spheres and a dielectric layer between them). As I know, the electric field in spherical capacitor is $E=\frac{Q}{4\pi \varepsilon\varepsilon_0 r^2}\sim \frac{1}{r^2}$. Inserting this in $\lambda(r)$ expression: $\lambda(r) \sim \frac{v}{(\frac{1}{r^2})^2} \sim r^4$. That is the place where I stuck because it's not a correct answer according to the task book answer sheet.

Could you please explain if there is any mistake in my solution and in that case what am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: I think the quantity $\lambda$ you are calling electrical conductance is actually electrical *conductivity*, typically denoted by $\sigma$.

Comment: Thanks, I got that. You know, there are some misconceptions in denotations between different books...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you don't know a priori that $E \propto 1/r^2$ in the case there is current flow. This assumes zero charge density between the two spheres, but in this case there is a non-zero charge density.

The equation you need to fall back to is $\vec \nabla \cdot \vec J = 0$, where $\vec J = \lambda \vec E$ is the current density. This is the continuity equation at steady state, and is the statement of charge conservation: it says there is no charge build-up between the spheres. You can use this equation to show that
$$ J = \frac{I}{4\pi r^2}$$
where $I$ is the total current. With this, you can deduce that
$$v=JE=J^2/\lambda\ \ \ \Rightarrow\ \ \ \lambda = \frac{J^2}{v}\propto\frac{1}{r^4}.$$

Comment: The tiny thing I don't understand however is why $J=\frac{I}{4\pi r^2}$ is deduced from the continuity equation at steady state. I know that $I=\int\limits_S Jds$, and in this case $S=4\pi r^2$ as the area of sphere surface...

Comment: It is likely easiest and most intuitive to just realize that if there is no charge build-up, the total current through every concentric sphere is the same ($I$). Then, due to spherical symmetry, the current density is the current divided by the area of this sphere. The other option is to solve the differential form of the continuity equation, which will likewise give you the $1/r^2$ dependence of $J$.